# How to find a set of points in a spherical space with specific radius around one point in a unorganized point cloud

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, point-clouds

I have a point cloud that consist of nearly 20000 points. We consider a point in the point cloud. I want to determine the set of points that are inside an spherical space around each point within the a predefined radius. In the image below there is a very clear illustration of what I mean,
[A point with a spherical space around it [Gross et al. (2007)][1]]  [1](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVI/3-W49/PartA/papers/57_pia07.pdf)

I have written the simplest way to find each set of point by using two loops. Here is the function,

```
void FindPointsInsideSphere(std::vector<Point>& points, double radius)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++)
        {
            if (i != j && Distance(points[i], points[j]) < radius)
            {
                points[i].Sphere.push_back(points[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the proposed algorithm is very time consuming. I wanted to know if there are any suggestions that can accelerate the process.

Comment: You can halve the amount of time used by using `Distance(points[i], points[j]) < radius` iff `Distance(points[j], points[i]) < radius`. Then your second loop variable would start at `i+1`.

Comment: @Albjenow Which part of the code do I have to change precisely?

Comment: @Albjenow I changed the code like this,                                             
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
{
 for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); j++)
 {
  if (i != j && Distance(points[i], points[j]) < radius)
  {
   if (Distance(points[j], points[i]) < radius)
    points[i].Sphere.push_back(points[j]);
  }
 }
}
 I think this is like your solution.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. Another check of the distance in the other direction isn't necessary. If point X is within the sphere of Y then (and only then) Y is within the sphere of X, right? So you can do 2 `push_back`s in the innermost `if` clause

Comment: divide the space in cubes with size=radius/2 and put particles to cubes, then chek each cube's particles against only neighboring cubes since other cubes will not be within range.

Comment: @Albjenow You are totally right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a similar question on stackexchange: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17971/search-for-all-nearest-neighbors-within-a-certain-radius-of-a-point-in-3d

After discussing with @AMA and googling I realized that both KDTree and uniform grids improve the time complexity of brute force.

---

#### Grid

Radius search complexity:

```
O(log(n) + k)
```

Where k is the approximate number of neighbours inside the sphere.

I've never personally tried this approach but as @AMA pointed it has better time complexity than kdtree query.

After a quick google search I found [this implementation on github](https://github.com/jeremynewlin/Accel).

---

#### KDTree

Radius search complexity:

```
O(sqrt(n) + k)
```

Where k is the approximate number of neighbours inside the sphere.

The best open source implementation the KDTree search [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/), wich comes with multiple languages support.

Take a look at [the manual](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf) in section: `3.1.4 flann::Index::radiusSearch`

If you want to implement this by yourself you can take a look at the [source code in githu](https://github.com/mariusmuja/flann)b for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if there are any suggestions that can accelerate the
>   process.

One well known way is to utilize any of [space-partitioning data structures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) from a long list.
The easiest to implement (arguably) is a [simple 3D grid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_(computational_geometry)).

Comment: I think that pointing him to use space-partitioning data structures is a good point. However, even if a 3D grid is the simplest structure to implement, it's not the right structure to perform a raius search around each point, wich is what he is asking about.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia Why not? First one finds cells which are intersected by the sphere and then tests against all the points in those cells.

Comment: In my opinion, that is way less efficient than using a data structure, like a KDTree or a BallTree, wich were specifically conceived to perform this kind of search operations. I'm not saying that you can't achieve the same using a 3D grid, I'm just saying that there are better data structures for radius search.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia With any tree one would also need to find leafs that are intersected by the sphere. The principle is absolutely the same.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia Without knowing about the structure of the point cloud, we can't say that much about such efficiencies. k-d-trees for example can be led astray. AMA stating that 3D grids are easy to implement, however, is obviously a true statement. Having a solution that works and that is easy to implement might be preferred over a solution that could, under certain circumstances, shave off nanoseconds. In any case, using 3D grids is obviously far more better than the naive solution in the question, therefore the answer is a valid one.

Comment: @Aziuth I understand both of your points of view and I'll try to explain my reasoning. 3D grid are indeed easy to implement, but the query system that ADAM propose (intersecting cells with the sphere and then compare against points in cell) is far more complex both in terms of implementation and runtime. I've never seen this kind of implementation for radius search but I don't think that it would be much more efficient than brute force.

Comment: @Aziuth And to now to defend kdtrees. Regarding the implementation it is not much more difficult than implementing a 3D Grid. In addition. I cannot compare the perfomance of a kdtree radius search versus the 3D Grid that ADAM proposes as I'm not aware of an existing implementation of that (witch is also a plus for kdtree where you can find many open source implementations and tutorials for radius search), but when comparing to brute force the perfomance gain it's not some nanoseconds under certain circunstances, it's way more.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia I don't think that this discussion converges. So I will state my points and arguments and leave.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia At some point I implemented both 3D grid and a balanced k-d tree. Main advantage of well-balanced k-d tree is its ability to discard big empty spaces very efficiently. It makes it more suitable for applications like ray-tracing (what I used it for). However, this is greatly irrelevant for the task of finding points in a spherical neighborhood. On the other hand, finding leafs of k-d tree that are intersected by the sphere of a given radius is **more** complex than for grid. Performance-wise I expect them to be similar, both **much** faster than brute-force.

Comment: I googled a bit. I was wrong about the time complexity of radius search in uniform grids. Didn't wanted to avoid the convergence of the discussion, I just wanted to expose my points and I never checked the uniform grid for radius search algorithm.

Comment: @DaviddelaIglesia I have the feeling that you see things far too complex. We don't need hyper-optimization. It suffices to add and subtract the radius from all axis-wise values of the center, take all 3D grid cells that cover this interval and compare their points as in the naive algorithm. Of course we could shave off some more cells by some tricks, but the important thing is that we simply rule out most of the points before we start comparing. As for kd-trees, they are basically the same as regular grids if the points happen to be somewhat evenly distributed.